# Unity - paint a texture with alpha to make it dissapear partially

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, alpha

I am trying to achieve this effect, I want to "paint" the image with alpha, like erasing part of the image exactly where the user touches or uses the mouse.

I don't know where to start.
[image: Example of the effect]

Answer (score 0):

You could put each image on a separate [Layer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) and tell your "eraser brush" to ignore the layer behind the one you want to erase using a [LayerMask](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html). When the user clicks on the image, it erases part of the image on the first layer, but leaves the image behind it alone.

Credit to *Statement* from [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8715/how-do-i-use-layermasks.html):

> LayerMask, or any "Mask" in Computer Science, is an integer which uses
>   its 32 bits to represent different flags. While it is an integer, the
>   value doesn't mean anything useful numerically. What matters is which
>   flags are turned on or off.
>
> In the case of LayerMask, each flag (each bit) represents one layer.

The layers are selectable at the top of the inspector for each `GameObject`, you can add and name layers there, and also choose to view different combinations of them (see pic).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have 2 textures on asingle plane:
- Make a custom shader with 3 textures (background, foreground, mask)
- Then you can paint into that mask texture with grayscale color and shader fades the 2 textures based on the mask color (example, if color is full white, only foreground is visible)

Or if you want to have 3D object behind a separate texture plane (and you only need to erase the existing texture, not draw the same pattern back)
- Could use any default texture which supports alpha
- Just paint into the MainTexture in the material, painting with color alpha 0 makes the area transparent
- Texture needs to have [x] read/write enabled in the importer settings to allow drawing on it

Some related links:

- Basic pixel drawing example from unity docs: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord.html
- Old demo scene, painting to texture and using dissolve shader : http://unitycoder.com/blog/2011/08/10/painting-holes-with-shader-v2-0/

And search for unity blend 2 textures with mask, unity draw to texture etc. to find more examples & shaders.